# Integrating GW sonarqube accelerator with Guidewire

Tags: sonarqube, guidewire, accelerator

I am trying to integrate GW sonarqube accelerator with Guidewire BillingCenter 10. I have performed all the steps mentioned in the accelerator document. The sonarqube accelerator is supposed to find all the code violations and import the violations to sonarqube server. However, the code inspection result file gets generated in the GW billingCenter installation directory but the accelrator is expecting the file to be under **C:\BillingCenter\gradle\cache\daemon\6.5.1\ **

Below is the exception I get: java.io.FileNotFoundException:C:\BillingCenter\gradle\cache\daemon\6.5.1\inspectionResults.descriptions.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

**Any idea on why the accelerator is expecting the files to be on a different location when the file is actually generated in a different location?**

I did try placing the generated inspection results in the folder C:\BillingCenter\gradle\cache\daemon\6.5.1\ and I could see the results being shown on the Sonarqube server as GOSUE issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this accelerator does not work at least with version 10.
Currently one of the customer is fixing the accelerator by rewriting it pretty much in-depth.
And you are correct with the mixup paths. The GW inspections executes in different "current directory" than the process that is trying to pick it up from the SonarQube Gosu scanner. Hence they can never be found.
And just to note this is for all the Guidewire core apps.
Also worth mentioning that this seems to be only an issue with the gradle wrapper. There were successfull tests with the simple bash wrapper and it worked so it is only an issue with the correct process chaining and current directory.

There are other functionalities that are also not functioning as you would expect. For example the lines of code needs additional coding in order to work.
The new fixes are hoped to be released at some point in near future and Guidewire might republish the fixed version - if all goes well. So stay tuned on the Marketplace.

As an alternative or in the mean time you can have a look at https://github.com/FRI-DAY/sonar-gosu-plugin which is available but works differently than the GW accelerator. Also be mindful about the licence and implications.

Comment: I'll post the details of the final fixes for the path once i have it